# colspan does not work in jquery toggle or show hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am assuming that `toggle()` `show()` and `hide` turns a element into a block element therefore disabling the capabilities to use `colspan`. When I am not hiding the TR, colspan works perfectly. as soon as a toggle or do the show hide, it no longer works.

Is there a jquery method out there that will successfully show and hide a table row while mainting the table cell row.

I somewhat found the solution considering the following.

## HTML

```
<h3 class="tac"><?php echo 'Communications';?></h3>
<br/><br/>
<table class="projects-table-style deposit-table communication" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Consultant</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Rating</th>
        <th>Communications</th>
        <th>Last Bid</th>
        <th>Memorandum</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $i = 0;
foreach ($comments as $comment):
        $class = null;
        if ($i++ % 2 == 0) {
            $class = ' class="altrow"';
        }
    ?>
    <tr<?php echo $class;?>>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $comment['User']['username']; ?>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $comment['User']['Country']['name']; ?></td>
        <td>Rating</td>
        <td>
            x communcations
            <a href="#" class="reply-to">Reply</a>
        </td>
        <td>Last Bid</td>
        <td>Memorandum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none" class="reply-box">
        <td style=" background: #fff" colspan="7">
            <table width="100%">
                <?php foreach($comment['Comment'] as $com): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td width="20%">
                        <?php echo $com['From']['username']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $com['comment']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td width="15%">
                        <?php echo $com['created']; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </table>
                 <?php echo $this->Form->create('Project');?>
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('message',array('type'=>'textarea','cols'=>'77','style'=>'margin-right:0px;padding:0px;'));?>
                <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit', true,array('attribute'=>'value')));?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

## JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.reply-to').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().next().toggle('slow');
        return false;
    });
});
```

So long as I toggle `.reply-box` which is appended to the TR. the TD element nested within will maintain its table-cell structure and will still keep the colspan attribute. just wanting to know if anyone else knows a better solution.

Comment: Please include code to help you better

Comment: Show to code, even better make a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: the code i provided is actually a solution after messing around but just curious to know if there is a better one

Comment: If you're going to post HTML that's generated using a server-side language, could you post the HTML post- rather than pre-generation? Makes it much easier to read and work with.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery API for [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) says this:

> This is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'block'), except that the display property is restored to whatever it was initially. If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline.

However, I'm not sure how it will function if the element is originally hidden (using `display: none` in either a CSS declaration or inline style); though I couldn't get it to break in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C8X4W/) so I think it should function correctly.

Comment: if the original element is hidden by a class, `.show()` adds an inline-style, which overrides the `display`-setting of the class. additionally, `.show()` checks the persistance of the style-attribute and enhances it